# What syntax should I use in the header of a function taking a two dimensional array as an argument in C

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I want to create a function that takes in the pointer to a two dimensional array that will modify the elements of this array. 
When I want to do the same thing with a one dimensional array, the thing is simple - I simply use the name of this array

```
void foo(int *array) {
    //CODE
}

int main() {
    int test[5] = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4};
    foo(test);
    return 0;
}
```

But what can I do in terms of two dimensional arrays? I tried to use this syntax:

```
#include <stdio.h>
void foo(int array[][]) {
    printf("%d", array[0][0]);
}

int main(void) {
    int array[2][2];
    array[0][0] = 3;
    foo(array);
}
```

but it did not work. Why is it not possible ot use this? How are two dimensional arrays treated in C?

Comment: Where is the code that uses a 2d array?

Comment: Show us your unsuccessful attempt so we can see where the mistake is.

Comment: I'm guessing you tried `int**` and got blocked by your wise compiler?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you have to realize that `void foo(int array[x])` and `void foo(int* array)` are 100% equivalent, because when you use the array syntax as part of a function parameter, it gets silently adjusted by the C compiler into a pointer to the first element. This is the reason why your original code works.

When using 2D arrays, there's no difference: you would write `void foo(int array[x][y])`. This too gets adjusted to a pointer to the first element. As it turns out, C does not actually support 2D arrays - what we have here is *an array of arrays of int*. The first element of an array of arrays of int, is an array of int.

How do we write a pointer to an array  of int then? With the *array pointer* syntax: `int(*)[y]`. You can think of it as if this pointer points at "the whole array".

And this is the reason why we get away with writing things like `void foo(int array[][y]);` - the inner-most dimension doesn't matter, since the parameter will get adjusted to an array pointer anyway.

C is deliberately designed this way to make functions match the rule of "array decay", which means that whenever an array name is used in an expression, it "decays" into a pointer to the first element. And this also makes it impossible to pass an array by value.

Example:

```
void foo(int array[2][5]) {
    //CODE
}

int main() {
    int test[2][5] = 
    {
      {0, 1, 2, 3, 4},
      {0, 1, 2, 3, 4}
    };

    foo(test);
    return 0;
}
```

Where all of these

```
void foo(int array[2][5])
void foo(int array[][5])
void foo(int array[666][5])
```

get silently adjusted by the compiler to be the same as

```
void foo(int (*array)[5])
```

Answer (score 2):

You can pass two dimensional array (actually a pointer to an array of arrays) to a function by declaring any of function prototypes

```
void foo1(int arr[][10]);
void foo2(int (*arr)[10]);
```

For C99 and latter these will also work

```
void foo3(int n, int arr[][n]);
void foo4(int n, int (*arr)[n]);
```

Then call your function

```
int arr[5][10] = { /*...*/ };
// code ... 
foo1(arr);
foo3(10, arr);
// code ...
```

Comment: By doing what you suggested, I will only pass the array to the function, not the pointer to the array.

Comment: @Aemilius - Wanna bet?

Comment: @Aemilius: then the code in your question also passes the one-dimensional array, instead of a pointer?

Comment: @Aemilius What StoryTeller is saying is that arrays in C are passed as an actual pointer.  The reason why multi-dimensional arrays require the additional annotations such as `int arr[][10]` (note that only the first `[]` can be empty) is so the compiler can properly dereference the single pointer passed.

Comment: @Aemilius By language design, you cannot pass arrays by value to a function.

Comment: I would avoid the obscure `[*]` syntax, as the type will have to be completed at the function definition anyway. Better to use the proper, explicit bounds in both the declaration and the definition.

Comment: @Lundin; Just listed the different possibilities.

Comment: Well there's also `int arr[1][n]` and `int arr[*][n]` and `int arr[n-INT_MAX-1][n]` and `int arr[static const 666][n]` and... but that doesn't mean we should be using them :)

Comment: It's not clear from your answer, but in the function definition, you have to use the `[n]` versions and not the `[*]` versions. IMO it would be better to not even mention the `*` version